# Trying to automate an R script that always runs against one dataset and conditionally against another

Tags: r

Very new to R and trying to modify a script to help my end users.

Every week a group of files are produced and my modified script, reaches out to the network, makes the necessary changes and puts the files back, all nice and tidy. However, every quarter, there is a second set of files, that needs the EXACT same transformation completed. My thoughts were to check if the files exist on the network with a file.exists statement and then run through script and then continue with the normal weekly one, but my limited experience can only think of writing it this way (lots of stuff is a couple hundred lines)and I'm sure there's something I can do other than double the size of the program:

```
if file.exists("quarterly.txt"){
     do lots of stuff}
else{
     do lots of stuff}
```

Comment: I would make a function out of `do lots of stuff` and then just call the function, so you don't need to repeat the code

Comment: I agree with @starja but also the way you wrote the pseudo code would only access your weekly files if 'quarterly.txt' does not exist. If you want it to always happen regardless of 'quarterly.txt' existing, don't put it in your else statement.

Comment: I'll give the function route a try, makes sense to me, starja. And thanks for the reminder lemonlin, I've not done much scripting or coding in years, time to get remedial.

Answer (score 0):

Both starja and lemonlin were correct, my solution was to basically turn my program into a function and just create a program that calls the function with each dataset. I also skipped the 'else' portion of my if statement, which works perfectly (for me).